# Special element of a commutative ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $S $ be a multiplicative subset of $R $. I am looking for an equivalence condition for the following property in $R $:

> Property: There exists a fixed  element $s\in S $ such that for each idempotent element $e $ of $R $ we have either $se=0$ or $s (1-e)=0$.

Note: Above property has a geometric interpretation, actually, $s $ is an element that annihilates a set of idempotents whose closure is a connected component in the $Spec (R) $, when $s $ is not a unite element.

Comment: The collection of clopen subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ on whose complement $s$ vanishes identically forms a filter (it is closed under intersections, enlarging the subset, and doesn't contain the empty set). Your property is equivalent to it being a maximal filter. The usual construction using Zorn's lemma should show that such an element always exists.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed the question.

Comment: Your comment is useful for me.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about filters?